# The group $S_n$ with a subgroup order $\varphi(n)n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Proof that the group $S_n$ has a subgroup which order is $\varphi(n)n$ and then
show that the group $S_{625}$ has subgroup which order is $5^6$.

Comment: Hello @Anna Tokarska, welcome to MSE. Can you explain us in your question what your exact problem is and what you have tried yourself already? Questions in the style 'this is the problem, what's the answer' are not always well received on MSE.

Comment: Why dont you show your efforts / attempts?

Comment: The answer depends very much on your background. I could tell you that such a group is provided by the normaliser of the image of the right regular representation of a cyclic group of order $n$, but does this resonate with you?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Consider all maps $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ that are bijective and of the form $x\mapsto ax+b$. Show that these maps form a group under composition.  How many choices are there for $a$, how many for $b$?

Comment: Sir, how can we prove the map $f$ from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to itself such that $f(x)=ax+b$ is injective?. $ax+b=cy+d$ imply $x=y$? How? Please explain.

Comment: Further, $0$ maps to  $a•0+b$ so this map need Not be homomorphism in all cases? Under what conditions this map is automorphism?